# In react project before does not work but after work

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

When hover before effect background does not see. But after effect background work. I try a different ways. I also use z-index but it also does not work.

```
   .img-hover {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-hover img {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.img-hover::after {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.294);
      content: "";
      transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .img-hover:hover::after {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
    .img-hover::before {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.294);
      content: "";
      transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    }
    .img-hover:hover::before {
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
```

But the code does not work. I try to find  out but

Comment: please add jsx or HTML code too, then it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have substituted img with no src but width and height and background pink and also slowed the transitions to 7s on the before and after pseudo elements.

You will see that the before is working as well as the after - the before shrinks the covering down to the right bottom and the after shrinks it down to the top left.

i.e. I cannot see what is not working in regard to the pseudo elements.

However, note that there is a transition specified for the actual img element but nothing is changed on the actual img on a hover so there is nothing happening to the actual img, only to the overlaid pseudo elements.

```html
<style>
   .img-hover {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-hover img {
  transition: 0.4wis ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
.img-hover::after {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.294);
      content: "";
      transition: all ease-in-out 7s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .img-hover:hover::after {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
    .img-hover::before {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.294);
      content: "";
      transition: all ease-in-out 7s;
    }
    .img-hover:hover::before {
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="img-hover">
    <img src="">
    </div>
```